# Sklearn.impute Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I want to fill the `np.nan` values with the mean with sklearn `SimpleImputer`, but a `valueError` is raised.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
imputer.fit(house_numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and have error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 1.  2.  3.  4. nan  7.  8.  9.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single 
feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

If your error is the same, try to reshape your house_numeric so:

```
house_numeric = house_numeric.reshape(-1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer above, is pretty good. First, reshape your data, then the imputer.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

# Setup the Imputation transformer: imp
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
```